# ASP.NET Can I manually submit my form at code behind stage

Tags: asp.net

I want to set a hidden field for a form when I set a button then have this maintain its state through all subsequent button clicks.

Is it possible to do a form post in the code behind to faciliate this, at the moment I'm doing a response.redirect but this loses the state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect will initiate a different request to the target page. If you still want to keep this behaviour, add query string parameters to "imitate" the hidden input fields.

Example:

```
<form method="get" action="redirect.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
    ...
</form>
```

Is similar to:

```
Response.Redirect("redirect.aspx?foo=bar");
```

**Note**: There will be different limitation between GET and POST requests (mainly the maximum URL length and encoding), so this may not always work depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the value in the ViewState.  That's essentially the same thing as using a hidden input, and ViewState will keep it's value automatically across postbacks.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to use the session, the query string, or a database.